# Calculate DATEDIFF with IDs

Tags: mysql, datediff

I'm an SQL beginner, so the other thread didn't really help me.

I have a table in my DB titled 'mission' which stores the IDs and dates of each mission that takes place. What I want to do is count the days between each entry and present that in another column.

I have found that the DATEDIFF function would be best to use for this.

```
id,name,campaign_id,real_date,hist_date,mission_status
1,"The Fall of France I",2,2013-12-08,"1940-05-11 11:00:00",2
2,"The Fall of France II",2,2013-12-15,"1940-05-15 15:30:00",2
3,"The Fall of France III",2,2013-12-22,"1940-05-21 15:30:00",2
4,"The Fall of France IV",2,2014-01-05,"1940-05-24 05:30:00",2
5,"The Fall of France V",2,2014-01-12,"1940-06-01 05:30:00",2
6,"The Fall of France VI",2,2014-01-19,"1940-06-12 13:10:00",2
```

I would like the table to list the mission's id in column 1, its hist_date in column 2 and the difference between each date entry in days in column 3.
Ex.

```
 id,hist_date,diff
    1,"1940-05-11 11:00:00",0
    2,"1940-05-15 15:30:00",4
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate date difference from previous row of each unique ID in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45762531/calculate-date-difference-from-previous-row-of-each-unique-id-in-mysql)

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: Which dbms???  SQL is just a language used by multiple dbms.  Each dbms has their own syntax.  It's useless if people give you solution to the wrong dbms.

Comment: Yes, this is SQL Server. Not sure if this is pertinent, but I use MySQL Workbench to access it.

Comment: Have a look at my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (T-SQL). It works even if your Id column is not continuous which can occur, for example, if a record is deleted.

```
SELECT A.Id, A.hist_date, ISNULL(DATEDIFF(Y, Max(B.hist_date), A.hist_date), 0) AS diff 
    FROM Mission AS A
    LEFT JOIN Mission AS B ON B.Id<A.id
    GROUP BY A.Id, A.hist_date
```

Result

```
Id  hist_date               diff
1   1940-05-11 11:00:00.000 0
2   1940-05-15 15:30:00.000 4
3   1940-05-21 15:30:00.000 6
4   1940-05-24 05:30:00.000 3
5   1940-06-01 05:30:00.000 8
6   1940-06-12 13:10:00.000 11
```

Comment: This worked at least. This pretty much covers it, even though it didn't work for some reason. Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Comment: ISNULL is T-SQL syntax. Try IFNULL if you're using MySQL.

Comment: Ah right, now it seems to be objecting to DATEDIFF though.

Comment: In MySQL you must remove the first parameter Y from DATEDIFF parameter list.

Comment: Thanks buddy. That worked. Now how would I possibly make the table show only ones in a particular range of dates?

Comment: You can add a WHERE clause line between LEFT JOIN line and GROUP BY line: For example
WHERE A.hist_date BETWEEN '1940-05-21 00:00:00.000' AND '1940-05-24 23:59:59:999'

Comment: Thanks. It seems that the dates go backwards and forwards (i.e are not continuous throughout), how could we compensate for that?